# How best to capture variables from within a for-loop in Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have two querysets: `type` and `age_group`.

type queryset:
`<QuerySet [<Type: Cat>, <Type: Dog>, <Type: Other>]>`

age_group queryset:
`<QuerySet [<AgeGroup: Young>, <AgeGroup: Baby>, <AgeGroup: Adult>, <AgeGroup: Senior>]>`

I loop through these from within my template form so that I can grab the pk when one has been selected, but I cannot capture the variable from within the for loop. How do I capture a variable from within a for loop when using Django? I want to capture pk for `type` and pk for `age_group` and then use both to filter the model `Animal` and return a filtered list that matches the user's preferences. A directory search function, essentially.

Template:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
        <h1>Animal Search</h1>

    <form class="form-inline" action= '.' method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
       
         <select name= "TypeSearch" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="animal_list_type">
         <label class="sr-only type" for="animal_list_type">SEARCH</label>
             {% for i in animal_type_list %}
                    <option value="{{i.pk}}">{{i}}</option> #how to capture the selected pk??
            {% endfor %}
         </select>

         <select name="AgeSearch" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="animal_list_ageGroup">
         <label class="sr-only ageLabel" for="animal_list_ageGroup">SEARCH</label>
             {% for j in age_group_list %}
                    <option value="{{j.pk}}">{{j}}</option> #how to capture the selected pk??
            {% endfor %}
         </select>

        <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" onclick="window.location='{% url 'animals:matches_list' pk=4 %}'; return false;">
        <input type="submit" onclick="window.location='{% url 'animals:animals' %}'; return false;" value="Cancel">
    </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
    class VisitorSearchView(View):
    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        #first tried ModelForm but couldn't figure out how to capture and iterate through one field of value options at a time
        animalList = Animal.type.get_queryset()
        animalList2 = Animal.ageGroup.get_queryset()
        context = {
            "animal_type_list": animalList,
            "age_group_list": animalList2
            }

        return render(request, "animals/landing.html", context)

    def post(self, request, pk=None):
        theForm1 = AnimalSearchForm(request.POST)
        success_url = reverse_lazy('animals:matches_list')
        print(pk)
        print(theForm1)
        filler_for_now = Animals.objects.all()
        context = {
                'theMatches': filler_for_now
            }
        return render(request, success_url, context)
```

model.py

```
    class Animal(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=False)
        type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=False, null=True)
        ageGroup = models.ForeignKey(AgeGroup, max_length=300, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=False, null=True)
        age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        sex = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SEX, blank=False, null=False, default='NA')
        breedGroup = models.ManyToManyField(BreedGroup, blank=False)
        breed = models.ManyToManyField(Breed, blank=False)
        tagLine = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
        goodWithCats = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default='Not Enough Information')
        goodWithDogs = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default='Not Enough Information')
        goodWKids = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default='Not Enough Information')
```

urls.py

```
    app_name = 'animals'

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.AnimalListView.as_view(), name='animals'),
    path('landing/', views.VisitorSearchView.as_view(), name='landing'),
    path('matches/<int:pk>', views.VisitorSearchView.as_view(), name='matches_list'),

]
```

forms.py #(originally tried to use ModelForm but couldn't figure out how to grab the pk for both `chooseType` and `chooseAge` fields so chose to try to just use querysets from view)

```
    class AnimalSearchForm(ModelForm):
    chooseType = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Animal.objects.values_list('type', flat=True).distinct(),empty_label=None)
    chooseAge  = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Animal.objects.values_list('ageGroup', flat=True).distinct(), empty_label=None)
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        exclude = '__all__'
```

Outside of Django, this would be a simple problem to solve. How do I capture a variable from within a for loop when using Django? I have tried to instantiate a variable outside the for-loop and then update that based off selection from within, but it seems that this cannot be done via the template...?

Comment: Show your view in the question

Comment: Okay. Will do. Thanks. My view is admittedly a mess as I am just trying to understand  the basics and how to pass the pk through. I first tried using ModelForm and now am just trying to use querysets via the view.

Comment: just show all the code you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the real issue here is that you really should be using `FormView` to display a form together with `DetailView` to display model data, in this particular case you should do something like this:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import FormView, DetailView

class VisitorSearchView(FormView, DetailView):
    model = Animal
    template_name = 'animals/landing.html'
    form_class = AnimalSearchForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data # Dict of submitted data
        # handle form validation and redirect

    def get_context_data(self, request):
        context = super(VisitorSearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        animals = Animal.objects.all() # or use a custom filter
        context['animals'] = animals
        return context
```

Then in your **landing.html**

where you want a list of animal `types`:

```
{% for animal in animals %}
    {{ animal.type }}
{% endfor %}
```

and where you want a list of animal `ages`:

```
{% for animal in animals %}
    {{ animal.age }}
{% endfor %}
```

declare your `form` normally as you would.

Comment: And just use `{{ form.as_p }}` to show your form, don`t do any of this unnecessary shenenigans.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and I get the same problem of not being able to capture the pk value because it is in a for loop. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Are you saying I don't need to pass the pk value if I use FormView? What is the benefit of using FormView? The docs didn't explain it much.

Comment: With Form View, you can access the submitted data by using `form.cleaned_data` inside `form_valid` method. Override `form_valid` method and do redirection there as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: But you are still writing a lot of unnecessary code. Please refer to the example form view in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview. You can simplify your work a lot by following the Django way of coding.

Comment: you can pass the pk in the same way you do with regular views, to get it inside the CBV use `self.kwargs['pk']`

Comment: the benefits of generic CBVs is that you write significantly less code

Comment: @ArjunAriyil  @SLDem This has helped a lot. I am able to return one match using `DetailView` as expected but I cannot return all matches if I modify for `ListView`. I am not sure why. `animals = Animal.objects.get_queryset().filter(Q(type=self.kwargs['pk']) & Q(ageGroup=self.kwargs['pk2']))` is returning an empty queryset. If I set context to `context['animals'] = animals` then I get the first match. If I set context to `context = {'animals':animals}` I get no matches. I want a list of all matches. I am sure this is super simple and hopefully one day it will be for me.

Comment: What exactly would you like to see in your `animals` queryset?

Comment: @SLDem So if user selects "dog" `type` and "baby" `ageGroup` then I would want queryset to have all animal entries that match those two fields...so a queryset of puppies and then would, through `ListView`, show the queryset as a list of matches. Here I have the queryset of puppies currently in db: `<QuerySet [<Animal: name:Lambert, type:Dog, age_group:Baby, sex: F>, <Animal: name:Mowgli, type:Dog, age_group:Baby, sex:M>, <Animal: Theodore, type:Dog, age_group:Baby, sex:M>]`. I have only been able to return the first match (Lambert).

Comment: take a look at this question: I think you might find what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the **dot** from the `action` attribute. Empty string in action use the current URL for form submission. Form opening line will be like

```
 <form class="form-inline" action= '' method="post">
```